# mkbundle System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception error

Tags: linux, mono, archlinux, mkbundle

I'm trying to bundle an application I've made in monodevelop on archlinux.

Once I build the application in monodevelop I go to make a bundle with the following command:

```
mkbundle --deps file.exe --static
```

But the output is:

```
OS is: Linux
Note that statically linking the LGPL Mono runtime has more licensing restrictions than dynamically linking.
See http://www.mono-project.com/Licensing for details on licensing.
Sources: 1 Auto-dependencies: True
   embedding: /home/test/Test/Test/bin/Release/file.exe
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll
 config from: /usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll.config
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/gdk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gdk-sharp.dll
 config from: /usr/lib/mono/gac/gdk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gdk-sharp.dll.config
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/glib-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glib-sharp.dll
 config from: /usr/lib/mono/gac/glib-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glib-sharp.dll.config
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Security/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Cairo/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Cairo.dll
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/pango-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/pango-sharp.dll
 config from: /usr/lib/mono/gac/pango-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/pango-sharp.dll.config
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/atk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/atk-sharp.dll
 config from: /usr/lib/mono/gac/atk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/atk-sharp.dll.config
   embedding: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll
Compiling:
AS = as (default)
as -o temp.o temp.s 
as -o temp.o temp.s 

Unhandled Exception:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='cmd', CommandLine='/c "as -o temp.o temp.s "', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) <0x40c2f420 + 0x00637> in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='cmd', CommandLine='/c "as -o temp.o temp.s "', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) <0x40c2f420 + 0x00637> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Being that I'm statically linking mono I had to install mono-git from the AUR to ensure I had the static libraries.

I'm also not sure why it has two `as -o temp.o temp.s` listed.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 23NOV:
I have just re-confirmed that `as` and `cc` have been installed. The version output is located at: http://pastebin.com/ka25tjWZ

EDIT 24NOV:
As explained in the accepted answer; my mono wasn't compiled correctly.
I rebuilt using abs with the following PKGBUILD and its now working as expected.

```
# $Id: PKGBUILD 246414 2015-09-16 21:25:15Z daniel $
# Maintainer: Daniel Isenmann <daniel@archlinux.org>
# Contributor: Brice Carpentier <brice@dlfp.org>

pkgname=mono
pkgver=4.0.4.1
_pkgver=4.0.4
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="Free implementation of the .NET platform including runtime and compiler"
arch=(i686 x86_64)
license=('GPL' 'LGPL2.1' 'MPL' 'custom:MITX11')
url="http://www.mono-project.com/"
depends=('zlib' 'libgdiplus>=3.8' 'sh' 'python' 'ca-certificates')
options=('!makeflags' 'staticlibs')
provides=('monodoc')
conflicts=('monodoc')
source=(http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/${pkgname}-${pkgver}.tar.bz2
        mono.binfmt.d
        sgen_fix.patch
    build_fix.patch
    Microsoft.Portable.Common.targets
    fix-zlib-helper.patch)
md5sums=('f598b60a664dfebb1a5eef3e66a9a178'
         'b9ef8a65fea497acf176cca16c1e2402'
         '8a700b94bff7a913f920e95890d2fb4c'
         '30a5af1a4ff50b98f9e73cc2ae554115'
         'acbffadb0ac233c494b40dd5e79209a5'
         '62912ad289535bf841c140727e5c1165')
install="${pkgname}.install"

build() {
  cd "${srcdir}"/${pkgname}-${_pkgver}

  # build mono
  ./configure --prefix=/usr \
    --sysconfdir=/etc \
    --bindir=/usr/bin \
    --sbindir=/usr/bin \
    --disable-quiet-build \
    --disable-system-aot \
    --enable-static \
    --with-static_mono=yes \
    --with-mcs-docs=no 
  make

  # build jay
  cd "${srcdir}"/${pkgname}-${_pkgver}/mcs/jay
  make
}

package() {
  cd "${srcdir}"/${pkgname}-${_pkgver}
  make DESTDIR="${pkgdir}" install

  # install jay
  pushd "${srcdir}"/${pkgname}-${_pkgver}/mcs/jay
  make DESTDIR="${pkgdir}" prefix=/usr INSTALL=../../install-sh install
  popd

  # install binfmt conf file and pathes
  install -D -m644 "${srcdir}"/mono.binfmt.d "${pkgdir}"/usr/lib/binfmt.d/mono.conf

  #install license
  mkdir -p "${pkgdir}"/usr/share/licenses/${pkgname}
  install -m644 mcs/MIT.X11 "${pkgdir}"/usr/share/licenses/${pkgname}/

  #fix .pc file to be able to request mono on what it depends, fixes #go-oo build
  sed -i -e "s:#Requires:Requires:" "${pkgdir}"/usr/lib/pkgconfig/mono.pc
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

So I ssh'd a friend's ArchLinux and `mkbundle` works fine there, so I went back to your error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: ApplicationName='cmd',
>   CommandLine='/c "as -o temp.o temp.s "', CurrentDirectory='', Native
>   error= Cannot find the specified file   at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell

Originally I thought you were on Windows due to this error, but you said Linux so I disregarded it. I went to the source of `mkbundle` and I can see that your ArchLinux box and/or the Mono install is not correctly reporting the 'IsUnix' as `false` and thus it is not executing the AS cmd via a `system` call but is trying to use the Windows' `cmd` to execute it and thus is failing....

```
static bool IsUnix {
        get {
            int p = (int) Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
            return ((p == 4) || (p == 128) || (p == 6));
        }
    }

    static void Execute (string cmdLine)
    {
        if (IsUnix) {
            Console.WriteLine (cmdLine);
            int ret = system (cmdLine);
            if (ret != 0)
            {
```

Again, the ArchLinux 4.2.5-1 that I have access to has Mono 4.0.4.1 and works as expected.....

What is returned on your system for each of these lines?:

```
int p = (int) Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
var islinux = ((p == 4) || (p == 128) || (p == 6));
```

**Original:**

> ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
>
> ```
>    AS     Assembler command. The default is "as".
>
>    CC     C compiler command. The default is "cc" under Linux and "gcc" under
>           Windows.
> ```

Ref: `man mkbundle`

This is the same requirement as you would need if you were building mono itself, besides the `temp.s` assembler code it will also create  `temp.c` file that needs a c compiler. This is the bootstrap code to load/execute your CIL-based code.

If you are missing an assembler on your system, there are a number of packages, such as `binutils` that will satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. I'm on a linux system; And I have built mono from source so I know I have cc.

Comment: Opps, need more coffee, saw the 'cmd', assumed Windows, will update, but you still need an assembler, should have one if you installed the gcc dev package, try the binutils package

Comment: I'll have to verify my environmental variables (I know I didn't set any recently for CC or AS.

Comment: Do you have an assembler installed? Via binutils... or `nasm`, `yasm`, `fasm`, ...

Comment: Sorry; Posted that before I had finished my reply.

I have binutils installed. And can manually run `as` or `cc` from the command line so I know they are installed (100%).

I'm not at my development computer right now so I won't be able to verify for several hours.

Comment: I have just re-confirmed that `as` and `cc` have been installed. The version output is located at: http://pastebin.com/ka25tjWZ

Comment: That sounds like something I would have missed setting in mono-gits's package-build (I knew it was something stupid just couldn't figure it out)

Thanks for helping track this down. Once I rebuild mono-git and confirm I'll accept your answer. Thanks so much!